# Strange behavior with Camera

Tags: java, android, html

I am developing a hybrid app using android,js and html5.

My code is as follows:

java :

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.main);  

        WebView webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webkitWebView1);  
        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();  
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
        settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);  
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);  
        //To display the alert  
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());  
       webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());  
       webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {  
             public void onExceededDatabaseQuota(String url, String databaseIdentifier, long currentQuota, long estimatedSize,
                long totalUsedQuota, WebStorage.QuotaUpdater quotaUpdater) {   
                quotaUpdater.updateQuota(estimatedSize * 1);
        }  
    });  

    //load  html5 page

        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/index.html");  

       openCamera=new OpenCamera(webView,AvivaInsureActivity.this);  
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(openCamera,"camera"); 
  }

public class OpenCamera  {  
 private WebView mAppView;  
    private Activity context;  
    protected String _path;  
    private Bitmap bitmap;  

 public String getImagePath1() {  
        return imagePath1;
  }  

   public void setImagePath1(String imagePath1) { 
    this.imagePath1 = imagePath1; 
  }  

       public String getImagePath2() { 
        return imagePath2; 
  }

       public void setImagePath2(String imagePath2) { 
        this.imagePath2 = imagePath2; 
    }
     public void startCameraActivity1(){

       Date dt = new Date();     
       int date=dt.getDate();  
       int hours = dt.getHours();     
       int minutes = dt.getMinutes();   
       int seconds = dt.getSeconds();     

       String curTime = date+"_"+hours + "_"+minutes + "_"+ seconds;  
           imagePath1=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/"+curTime+".jpg";  
       File file1 = new File(imagePath1);  


       Uri outputFileUri1 = Uri.fromFile( file1 );  


        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
    intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri1 );  

      context.startActivityForResult(intent,0);

  }
```

similarly camer2 method. 
And js and html5:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function openCamera1(){ 
    camera.startCameraActivity1();  
    var path1=camera.getImagePath1();  
   //alert(path1);  
   document.getElementById("image1").src=path1;  
 }
```

html:

```
<div><input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm()" /><br />
</div>

<div><img id="image1" height="50" width="50" />" "<img id="image2"
height="50" width="50" /></div>  

@Override   
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
       //data.getExtras();
         if (requestCode== 0 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){   
            String imagePath1 =  "file://"+openCamera.getImagePath1();  
            System.out.println("Image Pathhhhhhhhhh11111111 :::::::::::: " + imagePath1);
```

...
}

Here "Data" is null!! How is it possible? Is it right what am i doing here??

The problem is that if i comment the alert(path1) and alert(path2) i am not able to load the image on img tag. Its displaying "?" instead. After i enable the alert or try for 3-4 times capturing the image, it is displaying me the image!

Please help to debug.

Comment: i think you need to use setimeout.Hope it is taking time to load the image.

Comment: how to set time out? Sorry, i did not get you...!

Comment: window.setTimeout(myMethod(), 3000);In myMethod() function you can use the code to display image.

Comment: but i might have to write this in a separate javascript right? can i write it in html page above??  My requirement is that i would like to opencamera1() and display it there only.

Comment: yes you need to write separate javascript function.You can opencamera using openCamera1() function and then send path1 as argument to another function.

Comment: in which function do i need to write this window.setTimeout()?? myMethod()??

Comment: In openCamera1() you will get the path1 next write this settimeout function.After that initialize this my Method and display the image from this funntion.

Comment: its not working! Camera function is not working then!

Comment: No it should work because we are just changing the call.So,can you share your recent code with errors?

Comment: function openCamera1(){ 
 camera.startCameraActivity1();
 var path1=camera.getImagePath1();
 window.setTimeout(timeout1(path1),3000);
 //document.getElementById("image1").src=path1;
 //timeout1(path1);
 //alert(path1);
 //document.getElementById("image1").src=path1;
} function timeout1(String path1){
 
 document.getElementById("image1").src=path1;
 //document.getElementById("image2").src=path2;
}

Comment: In timeout1 function no need to mention string and what type of error you are facing?

Comment: i am unable to load the image :-(

Comment: Once check the path that you are retrieving.If it is correct then it should work.

Comment: yep. its working fine. But timeout is device dependant right? I want to use any other alternative solution.

Comment: If your are familiar with jquery then you have an option called jquery delay.So,instead of timeout you can use this :-)

Comment: i don't want to use any framework like jQuery or sencha!

Comment: I ahve found the problem. But don't know how to resolve. The camera.getImagePath1() is being called before camerastartactivity is finished. So the image is not yet being written/captured to the specified path and hence the problem.

Comment: then from startactivity method return boolean value and check if boolean value is true then camer.getImagePath1().Hope you are in right way now.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it in this way :

add :

```
   function openCamera1(){     
        result = camera.startCameraActivity1();  
        path1=camera.getImagePath1();  
        path="file://"+path1;
        do{  
                 fileIndicator=camera.findEOF();  
             }while(!fileIndicator)  
                document.getElementById("image1").src=path;  
        }
```

And in OpenCamera add a method:

```
public boolean findEOF(){  
       File file=new File(imagePath1);  
       System.out.println("Inisde EOFL::::::::::::::"+file.length());  

        if(file.length()>0){ 
           System.out.println("Inisde length is::::::::::::::"+file.length());  
            return true;
      }         
       return false;

   }
```

So the problem was get imagePath() was being called before the image is written to the file.